# Change in internal energy is 0 in isothermal process

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, work

I am having trouble understanding why in an isothermal process, the change in internal energy is zero. I know that $\Delta U$ or $\Delta E=q+w$, and so in isothermal process $q=0$. But how does one show that $w =0$? Or is it necessary that if we are talking of isothermal process, we are not doing work on the system; why or why not? Or is it necessary that if $w$ is not equal to 0, then the process can't be isothermal; why? Please explain this. I found a similar question here but I was not able to understand anything from it.

Comment: Q is not zero in an isothermal process.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the similar question you mention?

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/113586/why-change-in-internal-energy-is-zero-in-isothermal-process

Comment: @march I thought that isothermal means temperature is constant which means the system does not exchange or take heat energy from the surroundings otherwise its temprature would have increased that is q=0//so how can you say q is not equal to zero??

Comment: I think the answers below have cleared things up for you, but just in case: $Q$ is the amount of energy added via heat. Energy being added via heat *does not necessarily lead to a change in temperature*; that is a common misconception that is important to clear up. The reason is outlined below: for an ideal gas, $U$ is proportional to $T$, so if $\Delta T=0$, then $\Delta U =0$. This means that whatever energy comes *in* via heat has to go *out* via work, or vice versa.

Comment: @march how or on what basis can one say that U is proportional to T

Comment: $U$ is proportional to $T$ [*only* for an ideal gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_theory). The statement "in an isothermal process, $\Delta U = 0$" is therefore true *only* for the ideal gas.

Comment: OK!! I have got it!! But I think I asked in my previous comment that how U is proportional to T in ideal gas

Comment: Follow the link that I posted. If that's not clear, ask another question about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Isothermal* means *constant temperature*, which in turn often means *constant internal energy* $\Delta U=0$. The reason is that temperature often "governs" the energy content or at least is a measure of it. Changes in internal energy very often (that is, very often in typical problems) only comes from changes in thermal energy. If there are no phase transformations (no latent heat exchanges), no chemical or magnetic changes, no difference in motion (no kinetic energy changes), etc., which all is very often the case when we consider a system, then the only thing left to cause energy changes is thermal energy. And that is directly bound to the temperature,which is our measure of thermal energy.

So, just because the energy content doesn't change, it *doesn't* mean that no energy is added. Energy can certainly be added as long as the same amount of energy is *removed* at the same time. Heat $q$ can be nonzero, no problem. If that is the case, then let's see what the energy conservation equation says:

$$\Delta U=q-w\Leftrightarrow 0=q-w\Leftrightarrow q=w$$

You see, there is nothing preventing a net heat inflow, as long as there at the same time is a *net work* done by the system. Our the other way around: there can easily be a net heat *outflow* if just there also is work done *on* on the system.

The isothermal condition doesn't prevent any of those energy transfers to be present, it only gives the requirement that $q$ and $w$ must be equal.

Comment: I think I said in my comment that  "isothermal means temperature is constant which means the system does not exchange or take # heat energy# from the surroundings"I agreed on this heat energy part only which is wrong also as you pointed out ... But still you didn't state how or why ∆U=0,in isothermal process other things I have understood like how ∆U can be zero by q = -w etc...etc..but just elaborate the part why in isothermal ∆U is equal to zero

Comment: @Freelancer, ah I see, I didn't get the actual question then. I have now updated the answer to address this. Let me know if this is fulfilling.

Comment: No,again it is the same thing all the other things you talked about are fine but I am not able to understand properly how constant temperature means constant internal energy !! Can you elaborate it a bit more??

Comment: Okay, no problem, let's think it over in a few steps. What kinds of energy would be a part of the internal energy?

Comment: I don't know about all the energies that are part of internal energy but I know that translational energy ,rotational energy,vibrational energy,bonding energy are included in this !!

Comment: @Steeven, this means, $\Delta U \neq 0$

Comment: It is not true that "isothermal means constant temperature, which in turn means constant internal energy".  An obvious counter-example is that of a system undergoing a phase transition (e.g., liquid water undergoing vaporization).  Heating increases internal energy while temperature remains constant during the phase transition.  Even for a single phase the statement is not true: the changing intermolecular forces during an expansion process require energy to be added or removed if the process is to be isothermal.  This answer should not be accepted as correct.

Comment: @tjd Thank you for the comment. That is actually exactly the point of the rest of the answer. I understand that this first sentence may be confusing, so I have added an "often". This should fix it.

Comment: Actually, it is not even "often true" that constant temperature means constant internal energy.  See the answer by user136963.  The statement is true for the special case of an ideal gas.  But it is not ever true for liquids or solids.  Even real gases diverge from ideality above 300 K; this is most easily seen in the variation of heat capacity with temperature.

Comment: @tjd It is for sure often the case in idealised scenarios, which are plentiful in modelling, training and education etc.

Comment: @Steeven While I think it is fair to say that increases in internal energy "often" increase the temperature, saying isothermal processes "often" have constant energy is simply untrue.  As user136963's answer makes clear, isothermal processes *only* have constant energy for ideal gases -- not for any other idealized process, nor any real process.

Comment: @tjd What exactly is the issue here? You don't like the word "often"? We are most likely dealing with an educational level question here, so I believe it applies just fine from my own experience. I will keep it with your comments here for future visitor's reference

Answer (score 6):

The quick answer is $\Delta U \neq 0$.

Let's look at some details.
In the special case where you are dealing with **ideal gas.** $$U = \frac{3}{2} nRT$$
Thus $$\Delta U = \frac{3}{2}nR\Delta T $$ Since the process is isothermal, $\Delta T$ is **zero**. Therefore $\Delta U = 0$. So it is not true that $q = 0$(that would be called adiabatic). Rather, $q = -w$.

The above analysis fails if the gas is **NOT** ideal. Since $U = \frac{3}{2}nRT$ is generally not true. But usually the ideal gas approximation works fine.

Comment: How did you get U=3/2×nRT I think you used an example can you generalise it ?? I only know basic things like ∆U=q+w etc..etc.. Can you please talk in theese terms??

Comment: Here is a nice Khan Academy video for deriving $U = \frac{3}{2} nRT: https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/thermodynamics/laws-of-thermodynamics/v/proof-u-3-2-pv-or-u-3-2-nrt  If you take this equation as a given law for ideal gas, your goal is to keep temperature CONSTANT. If you pump in some heat and fix the volume of the gas, then the temperature is going to increase. Thus intuitively the volume has to expand and $w = -q$ in order to guarantee that $T$ does not change.

Answer (score 2):

General expression for change in internal energy for 1 component 1 phase system:

$$dU = C_V dT + \left[T \left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}\right)_V - p \right] dV.$$

Considering ideal gas, the ideal gas law can be used, in which case the 2nd term on the right becomes zero (you can try it). Then, dU is just a function of temperature ONLY for ideal gas. Thus, in an isothermal process, dU is zero. Remember, because the ideal gas equation is used, the 2nd term becomes zero. For other systems (non-ideal gases or liquids), the equation of states (EOS) that describe their behavior are different!

Comment: This answer provides the general relationship between energy and temperature in a simple system -- applicable to solids, liquids, and gases, even during phase transitions.  The equation provided definitively shows that isothermal processes have constant energy only in special cases (e.g., ideal gases).  As such, this answer should be the one marked as correct.

Comment: I've edited your answer to use MathJax, which is the generally preferred way to write mathematical expressions here.  If you are unfamiliar with it, you can find a tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

To Freelancer,
I think what you need is a more intuitive answer. I try to give an answer without requiring you to have any knowledge in integral, thermodynamics, physical chemistry and statistical mechanic to understand it. The answer is actually quite simple; "Temperature is in fact an indicator of a system internal energy". In other words, when you measure the temperature of a system, let says a cup of water, the reading which is shown on thermometer is just internal energy times some constant, and this "internal energy times constant" stuff is what you called temperature (the actual equation according to statistical mechanic is far more complex, i had over-simplied it, but the idea is more or less the same). No equation...as i promised.

Comment: "Temperature is in fact an indicator of a system internal energy."  This is demonstrably false.  A system undergoing a phase transition (e.g., liquid water being vaporized) has increasing internal energy but constant temperature.